# How to do dimension reduction on training data set using R mapreduce?

Tags: r, mapreduce, hdfs, rhadoop

I am working with RHadoop rhdfs package to perform dimension reduction on a CSV input file with large number of columns. The output would be a selected subset of all columns. To make it simple, I am trying to take just the first 5 columns of the CSV file.

I am trying to apply mapreduce function to perform the dimension reduction using MR framework and using the HDFS storage instead of any in-memory processing.

My code is as follows:

```
transfer.csvfile.hdfs.to.hdfs.reduced =
                function(hdfsFilePath, hdfsWritePath, reducedCols=1) {
                        local.matrix = as.numeric()
                        hdfs.get(hdfsFilePath, local.Matrix, srcFS=hdfs.defaults("fs"))
                        transfer.reduced.map =
                                        function(.,M) {
                                                label <- M[,1]
                                                reduced.predictors <- M[,1:reducedCols]
                                                reduced.M <- cbind(reduced.predictors, label)
                                                keyval(
                                                     1,
                                                     as.numeric(reduced.M[,-1]))
                                        }
                         reduced.values =
                             values(
                                     from.dfs(
                                        mapreduce(
                                          local.matrix,
                                          map = function(.,M) {
                                                label <- M[,1]
                                                reduced.predictors <- M[,1:reducedCols]
                                                reduced.M <- cbind(reduced.predictors, label)
                                                keyval(
                                                     1,
                                                     as.numeric(reduced.M[,-1]))}
                        )))
                        to.dfs(reduced.values)
                }
```

It takes a train data set with predictor columns and label column as the last one. What I am trying is to reduce the number of predictors from 100 to 5 and `cbind` the class label column to the reduced predictors and finally store the reduced training data set into hdfs.

Right now I am storing the hdfs file in a local matrix by the name `local.matrix` which will need me to store the entire file in-memory. Is there a way I can by-pass the in-memory `local.matrix` by using

`to.dfs(local.matrix)` and then passing the HDFS storage location for local.matrix as `hdfsWritePath` into `transfer.csvfile.hdfs.to.hdfs.reduced function` ?